# R ggplot2 - legend at the bottom gets cut, how to find optimal number of columns for the legend on the fly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, legend

I want to make a plot with a legend at the bottom, but the legend gets invariably cut... Since it seems `ggplot2` cannot automatically determine the best number of columns in a legend at the bottom, I try to do it myself... with no success.

Say I have the following `mydf` data frame:

```
mydf <- data.frame(group=paste0('gr',1:10), var=paste('some long text -', LETTERS), value=runif(260, 0, 100))
head(mydf)
#  group                var     value
#1   gr1 some long text - A  7.941256
#2   gr2 some long text - B 50.740651
#3   gr3 some long text - C 89.068872
#4   gr4 some long text - D 77.572413
#5   gr5 some long text - E  9.792349
#6   gr6 some long text - F 35.194944
```

I want my output plot to have a width of 12 (inches).

When I make the plot with `ggplot2`, the legend takes more width than the plot and gets cut:

```
width_scale <- 12
grDevices::pdf(file='test.pdf', height=10, width=width_scale)
print(#or ggsave()
  ggplot2::ggplot(mydf, ggplot2::aes(group, value, fill=var)) +
    ggplot2::geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    ggplot2::scale_y_continuous("%") +
    ggplot2::theme_light() +
    ggplot2::theme(legend.text=ggplot2::element_text(size=1.5*width_scale),
                   legend.title=ggplot2::element_text(size=1.5*width_scale,face="bold"),
                   legend.position="bottom",
                   legend.key.size = grid::unit(width_scale/50, "inch"),
                   legend.key.width = grid::unit(width_scale/50, "inch"))
)
grDevices::dev.off()
```

It produces this plot:

[image: test1]

Since my legend gets cut for some reason, I tried to determine the optimal number of legend columns myself. I have to calculate it on the fly cause all of this goes into a function (but for this case, the answer should be 4).

Since the width of the plot is in inches, I tried to be smart about it and calculate the average size in inches for a level in the legend. Then the number of columns would be the plot width divided by the size of a single level, rounded down (minus the columns that the legend title would occupy).

```
#find optimal number of legend columns
ceiling_dec <- function(x, level=1) round(x + 5*10^(-level-1), level)
floor_dec <- function(x, level=1) round(x - 5*10^(-level-1), level)
letter_size <- 1.5*width_scale/72.27 #72.27 point in 1 inch
mean_level_size <- mean(nchar(levels(mydf$var))) * letter_size #this is the size in inches of a group level in the legend
mean_level_size <- mean_level_size + (width_scale/50) + (width_scale/50) #plus the size of the level key and some extra space
num_cols <- floor_dec(width_scale/mean_level_size, 0)
cols_to_remove <- ceiling_dec((3*letter_size) / mean_level_size, 0) #number of columns that the legend title (var) would occupy
num_cols <- num_cols - cols_to_remove
if (num_cols<=0){num_cols <- length(levels(mydf$var))}
if (num_cols>length(levels(mydf$var))){num_cols <- length(levels(mydf$var))}
num_rows <- ceiling(length(levels(mydf$var)) / num_cols)
if ((num_rows==1) & (num_cols<length(levels(mydf$var)))){num_cols <- length(levels(mydf$var))}
#
```

With this information, I would use `ggplot2` again to make the plot, passing the number of columns to `guide_legend`.

```
grDevices::pdf(file='test.pdf', height=10, width=width_scale)
print(#or ggsave()
  ggplot2::ggplot(mydf, ggplot2::aes(group, value, fill=var)) +
    ggplot2::geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    ggplot2::scale_y_continuous("%") +
    ggplot2::theme_light() +
    ggplot2::theme(legend.text=ggplot2::element_text(size=1.5*width_scale),
                   legend.title=ggplot2::element_text(size=1.5*width_scale,face="bold"),
                   legend.position="bottom",
                   legend.key.size = grid::unit(width_scale/50, "inch"),
                   legend.key.width = grid::unit(width_scale/50, "inch")) +
    ggplot2::guides(fill=ggplot2::guide_legend(ncol=num_cols))
)
grDevices::dev.off()
```

I thought I almost had it, but the results are never successful... see the code in this MWE produces the following plot...

[image: test1]

Why does the legend get cut like that? Why `ggplot2` doesn't choose the optimal number of columns automatically?

If I try to determine the optimal number of columns myself, how to do it? What am I doing wrong up there?

I know that the optimal number of columns in this case to pass to `guide_legend` (the `num_col` result of the chunk up there) should be 4, but I only know it *post hoc*... I would need to calculate this optimal number on the fly cause all this goes inside a function...

Thanks!

Comment: Well, the plot code is working fine.  Seems like `num_cols = 1` when I run your code with the dataset provided.  When I let `ggplot` choose the # of columns (just include `theme(legend.position='bottom')` within `theme()` and remove all other theme elements, the default plot uses 5 columns (which seems to work).  If you still want to specify the # of columns, check all your code above `num_cols <- floor_dec...`.  Something there is not quite right.

Comment: yeah I know there is something wrong with that portion, that is exactly my question... how do you let ggplot choose the number of columns automatically? If I don't specify them, the legend takes more width than the plot and gets cut...... see my edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked :

- reduce font size (width_scale instead of width_scale * 1.5)
- add a box around the legend

```
ggplot2::ggplot(mydf, ggplot2::aes(group, value, fill=var)) +
    ggplot2::geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    ggplot2::scale_y_continuous("%") +
    ggplot2::theme_light() +
    ggplot2::theme(legend.text=ggplot2::element_text(size=width_scale),
                   legend.box.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6),
                   legend.title=ggplot2::element_text(size=1.5*width_scale,face="bold"),
                   legend.position="bottom",
                   legend.key.size = grid::unit(width_scale/50, "inch"),
                   legend.key.width = grid::unit(width_scale/50, "inch"))
```

[image: See result]

You can adjust width_scale according to the number of elements in the legend :

```
mydf <- data.frame(group=paste0('gr',1:10), var=paste('some long text -', 1:50), value=runif(500, 0, 100))
width_scale <- 12 * 26 / length(unique(mydf$var))
```

[image: width_scale adjustement]

Comment: OK this seems to work, but still does not allow me to control for plot size depending on how large the legend is going to be... see I could have 2 levels or 50, but I wouldn't want the bars to be super small as the legend gets bigger, but rather the plot height to be larger. I guess it still is the best solution we can get

Comment: wouldn't my approach to calculate the optimal number of columns beforehand be modified so that it works? That way I would have control over the legend AND the plot size correcting plot height for number of rows...

Comment: what about adjusting width_scale to the number of different var elements? something like width_scale <- 12 * 26 /  length(unique(mydf$var)). I tried it with 50 legend elements and the graph size stayed quite stable, see my edit. Not sure we can make much more with the available options

Answer (score 3):

You could adjust `size` manually by altering the size value until the graphics match your requirements?

```
print(#or ggsave()
  ggplot2::ggplot(mydf, ggplot2::aes(group, value, fill=var)) +
    ggplot2::geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    ggplot2::scale_y_continuous("%") +
    ggplot2::theme_light() +
    ggplot2::theme(legend.text=ggplot2::element_text(size=14), legend.position = "bottom"),
                   legend.title=ggplot2::element_text(size=1.5*width_scale,face="bold"),
                   legend.key.size = grid::unit(width_scale/50, "inch"),
                   legend.key.width = grid::unit(width_scale/50, "inch"))
)
```

[image]

Comment: The question is exactly how to avoid doing it manually... it goes inside a function so the number of rows and size of text should be calculated automatically

Answer (score 2):

You can use `graphics::strwidth()` to get the size of the legend text, then use this for the calculation. This way, you can set any page size, font size, or legend size you want, independently, and still get the correct number of columns:

```
library(graphics)
library(ggplot2)
col_width = function(txt, key.width, key.spacing, ps) {
        txt.width = strwidth(txt, units="inches", ps = par(ps = ps))
        max(txt.width + key.width + 2*key.spacing)
}

opt.cols = function(txt, title, key.width, key.spacing, plot.width, ps) {
        title.width = strwidth(expression(bold(title)),  units="inches", ps = par(ps = ps))
        (plot.width - title.width) %/% col_width(txt, key.width, key.spacing, ps)
}

width_scale = 12
key.width = width_scale/50
key.spacing = width_scale/50
ps = width_scale * 1.5
num_cols = opt.cols(mydf$var, 'var', key.width, key.spacing, width_scale, ps)

ggplot(mydf, ggplot2::aes(group, value, fill=var)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity") +
        scale_y_continuous("%") +
        theme_light() +
        theme(legend.text = element_text(size = ps),
              legend.title = element_text(size = ps, face="bold"),
              legend.position = "bottom",
              legend.spacing.x = grid::unit(key.spacing, "inch"),
              legend.key.size = grid::unit(key.width, "inch"),
              legend.key.width = grid::unit(key.width, "inch")) +
        guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = num_cols))

ggsave('test.pdf', height=10, width=width_scale)
```

Comment: ok this is the approach I was actually hoping for, I will definitely try it though I already implemented the earlier answer. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi! So I am trying your code and seems to be doing exactly what I want , thanks! However, how can I prevent it to create this spurious `Rplots.pdf` file it produces? Thanks again!

Comment: seems like doing pdf(NULL) before and dev.off() after the `strwidth` lines works