# Make legend symbols smaller than default in R waffle plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, waffle-chart

I have a two-part waffle plot with a lot of little squares, and a legend that contains two squares. I would like to make the sizes of all of these squares to be the same.

There was an [issue](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle/issues/22) opened on GitHub about this, and the repo owner said that since waffle() returns a ggplot2 object, we can use guide() to do this.

I tried searching on documentation to do this and came up with

```
library(waffle)

phrase_count = 17345/10000
all_count = (22784085 - phrase_count)/10000

my_waffle = waffle(c("All"=all_count, "Phrases"=phrase_count), 
                   rows=43, 
                   size=0.6,
                   colors=c("#969696", "pink", "white"),
                   flip=TRUE)

my_waffle + guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=0.6)))
```

but this doesn't affect the size of the legend. I've seen people use `color`, `colour`, or `shape`, but none of these arguments work for me.

How do I get the size of squares in the legend to be the same as the size of the squares in the plot itself?

[image]

Comment: Did you give a try to `legend.key.size`, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62384008/13513328)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `theme()` for your legend key as the waffle object is from `ggplot2` nature as mentioned in comments by @Waldi:

```
#Code
my_waffle <- my_waffle + theme(legend.key.size = unit(3, "mm"))
```

Output:

[image]

Or maybe this:

```
#Code 2
my_waffle + theme(legend.key.height = unit(0.2, "cm"),
                  legend.key.width = unit(0.3, "cm"))
```

Output:

[image]