# Change the height and width of a legend box in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to change the size of the height of a legend to make the distribution of the names for when I save the image in a smaller format, it doesn't cut the legend. Maybe put in columns of four names in maximun, rather than in three.

```
ggplot(datW, aes(
  y = Proportion,
  x = Year,
  alluvium = group_strata, 
  stratum = metier_name
)) + 
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Class)) + 
  geom_stratum(width = 2/5) +
  #2/5 
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = metier_name),size = 2.8) +   
  theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels=datW$Year, breaks=datW$Year)
```

[image: Not cutted image]

[image: Image with cut]

I tried to change margins but it didn't work.

Comment: Please share the code you used to create your graph.

Comment: @Brenda Nogueira, welcome to stack overflow! Lots of users will be willing to help you, but please note the standard practice here is to post data and code sufficient for creating a minimally reproducible example. In the meantime, this may be helpful: https://r-graph-gallery.com/239-custom-layout-legend-ggplot2.html

Comment: Also, I can see that the top image has a complete legend and the bottom one cuts off a word. What is the difference in how you produced the 2 images? It seems like however you did the bottom one works...

Comment: Here is the code that I used for generate the plot:
ggplot(datW, 
       aes(y = Proportion, x = Year, alluvium = group_strata, stratum = metier_name)) + 
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Class)) + 
  geom_stratum(width = 2/5) +#2/5
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = metier_name),size = 2.8) + theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  scale_x_continuous(labels=datW$Year,breaks=datW$Year)
The diference is that one I saved as : ggsave("paper/Distribution_over_years.png",width=12, height=6)
and the other ggsave("paper/Distribution_over_years.png",width=11, height=6)

Comment: I've edited your code into your question for clarity. I think [this is what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18400432/903061). You could add to your plot `guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=4))`. The other option is to change the font to a smaller size when outputting a smaller file.

Comment: You can see answers for a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62324735/903061).